# Scala GADT instance Functor

Tags: scala, inheritance, scalaz, gadt, scala-cats

In Haskell I got:

```
data Foo a where
  Bar :: a -> Foo a
  Map :: (a -> b) -> Foo a -> Foo b

instance Functor Foo where
  fmap = Map
```

In Scala I came up with:

```
import cats.Functor

trait Foo[A]
case class Bar[A](t: A) extends Foo[A]
case class Map[A,B](fun: A => B,foo: Foo[A]) extends Foo[B]

implicit val fooFunctor: Functor[Foo] = new Functor[Foo] {
  def map[A,B](fa: Foo[A])(f: A => B) = Map(f,fa)
}
```

But `Bar(40).map(_+2)` gives me:

```
error: value map is not a member of Bar[Int]
```

I fairly new to Scala and don't know the way of inheritance that well.

*What am I missing?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to upcast `Bar(40)` to `Foo` explicitly, and import the syntax implicits:

```
import cats.syntax.functor._
(Bar(40): Foo[Int]).map(_+2)
```

You need the upcast because Scala will infer the type `Bar[Int]` for the expression `Bar(40)` and this then interferes with finding the appropriate implicit that adds the `map` method. For this reason you sometimes see helper methods in the companion object to do the upcast for you:

```
object Foo {
  def bar[A](a: A): Foo[A] = Bar(a)
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: I like this idea because it's really pragmatic. On the down side it generates quite some boilerplate for more complex GADTs and one has to call `bar(42).map(_+2)`.

Comment: Yeah, I can sympathise with that. I've written a macro for simpler GADT cases that turns `@GADT(Bar[String](x: Whatever), Baz[Int]) sealed trait Foo[A]` into `sealed trait Foo[A]; object Foo { case class Bar(x: Whatever) extends Foo[String]; def bar: Whatever => Foo[String] = Bar.apply _; // similarly for baz }` (although with functorhood provided via Coyoneda rather than directly embedded). A similar approach might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I thought a little bit about how one could solve this problem. Basically, we want to provide the functor operations even if only a super type is a functor. It seems to be impossible to express, that some higher-kinded type is the super type of an other, e.g. something like this is not possible: `def bla[F[_], R[_] <: F]`

We can however provide a conversion from R[*] to F[*] implicitly together with the functor for B:

```
abstract class ProvidesFor[R,F[_],FF[_[_]],A](val value: FF[F]) {
  def convert(r: R): F[A]
}
implicit def providesFunctorForBar[A] =
  new ProvidesFor[Bar[A],Foo,Functor,A](Functor[Foo]) {
    override def convert(r: Bar[A]): Foo[A] = r
  }
```

So the implict val will provide us with a functor for Foo and a convertion from Bar to Foo.

Now we can provide an implicit converstion to Functor.Ops like this:

```
implicit class FunctorOps[R[_],F[_],A](target: R[A])(implicit tc: ProvidesFor[R[A],F,Functor,A])
      extends Functor.Ops[F,A] {
  override val self = tc.convert(target)
  override val typeClassInstance = tc.value
  override def map[B](f: A => B): F[B] = typeClassInstance.map(self)(f)
  override def imap[B](f: A => B)(g: B => A): F[B] = map(f)
}
```

Now this works as expected:

```
Bar(1).imap(_+2)(_+5)
```

We can also do the same for Map:

```
implicit def providesFunctorForMap[A,B] =
  new ProvidesFor[Map[A,B],Foo,Functor,B](Functor[Foo]) {
    override def convert(r: Map[A,B]): Foo[B] = r
  }

Map((_:Int) + 1,Bar(5)).map(_+2)
```

For some strange reason I had to implement map and imap when extending Functor.Ops even though these methods are not abstract. In fact it compiles fine when I do not implement them but it fails at runtime with an AbstractMethodError. So somehow the compiler thinks the implementations are there but they are not. I suspect they are using some kind of byte code optimization tool that removes those implementations.